# ASP MVC Route resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Contests",
        "Contests/{id}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Contests", action = "Manage" },
         new { id = @"\d+" }
    );
}
```

When they are arranged that way the contest route is not reached and it displays resource not found. When I switch their places (the "default" stays second) the Manage route works fine but the default one doesn't work. I would be very happy if anyone helps me!

Comment: What do you mean the second one does not work? - `.../Home/Index/1` will direct to the `Index()` method of `HomeController` What url's are you using?

Comment: I fixed it when i swapped the places of the two routes thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out that switching the order works.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Contests",
        "Contests/{id}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Contests", action = "Manage" }, new { id = @"\d+" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Routes are suggested to be organized in a way that they be more specific to less specific on its way down.